# PowerShell Set-Content and Out-File - what is the difference?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, what's the difference between [`Out-File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Out-File) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)? Or [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) and `Out-File -append`?

I've found if I use both against the same file, the text is fully [*mojibaked*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

(A minor second question: `>` is an alias for `Out-File`, right?)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Here's a summary of what I've deduced, after a few months experience with PowerShell, and some scientific experimentation. I never found any of this in the documentation :(

*[**Update:** Much of this now appears to be better documented.]*

### Read and write locking

While `Out-File` is running, another application can read the log file.

While `Set-Content` is running, other applications cannot read the log file. Thus **never use `Set-Content`** to log long running commands.

### Encoding

[`Out-File`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/13d09dc8-2398-4d73-9449-1d01eb4e7808.aspx) saves in the [`Unicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx) (`UTF-16LE`) encoding by default (though this can be specified), whereas [`Set-Content`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847827.aspx) defaults to [`ASCII`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) (`US-ASCII`) in PowerShell 3+ (this may also be specified). In earlier PowerShell versions, `Set-Content` wrote content in the [`Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) (ANSI) encoding.

<sup>*Editor's note*: PowerShell as of version 5.1 *still* defaults to the culture-specific `Default` ("ANSI") encoding, despite what the documentation claims. If ASCII were the default, non-ASCII characters such as `ü` would be converted to *literal* `?`, but that is *not* the case: `'ü' | Set-Content tmp.txt; (Get-Content tmp.txt) -eq '?'` yields `$False`.</sup>

```
PS > $null | out-file outed.txt
PS > $null | set-content set.txt
PS > md5sum *
f3b25701fe362ec84616a93a45ce9998 *outed.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e *set.txt
```

This means the defaults of two commands are incompatible, and mixing them will corrupt text, so always specify an encoding.

### Formatting

As Bartek explained, `Out-File` saves the fancy formatting of the output, as seen in the terminal. So in a folder with two files, the command `dir | out-file out.txt` creates a file with 11 lines.

Whereas `Set-Content` saves a simpler representation. In that folder with two files, the command `dir | set-content sc.txt` creates a file with two lines. To emulate the output in the terminal:

```
PS > dir | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString()}
out.txt
sc.txt
```

I believe this formatting has a consequence for line breaks, but I can't describe it yet.

### File creation

`Set-Content` doesn't reliably create an empty file when `Out-File` would:

In an empty folder, the command `dir | out-file out.txt` creates a file, while `dir | set-content sc.txt` does not.

### Pipeline Variable

`Set-Content` takes the filename from the pipeline; allowing you to set a number of files' contents to some fixed value.

`Out-File` takes the data as from the pipeline; updating a single file's content.

### Parameters

`Set-Content` includes the following additional parameters:

- Exclude
- Filter
- Include
- PassThru
- Stream
- UseTransaction

`Out-File` includes the following additional parameters:

- Append
- NoClobber
- Width

For more information about what those parameters are, please refer to help; e.g. `get-help out-file -parameter append`.

Comment: `Set-Content` default encoding: translated to `(Get-Culture).Textinfo.ANSICodePage` (Windows 8.1, Powershell 4.0, CurrentCulture `cs-CZ`, CurrentUICulture `en-GB`, ANSICodePage `1250`, OEMCodePage  `852`, tested using `'řž'`string with different codes in above code pages).

Comment: Also note that `Out-File` has problems with long lines in certain situations.  For example:  `$x = [pscustomobject]@{A=('a' * 500); B=('b' * 500)}; $x | Out-File -Path myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 20):

`Out-File` has the behavior of overwriting the output path unless the `-NoClobber` and/or the `-Append` flag is set. `Add-Content` will append content if the output path already exists by default (if it can). Both will create the file if one doesn't already exist.

Another interesting difference is that `Add-Content` will create an ASCII encoded file by default and `Out-File` will create a little endian unicode encoded file by default.

`>` is <s>an alias</s> syntactic sugar for `Out-File`. It's `Out-File` with some pre-defined parameter settings.

Comment: Thanks, knowing the encoding differences is useful. You're not quite right, if you do `echo "" > $null | Add-Content abc.txt` it _doesn't_ create the file `abc.txt`, whereas Out-File would.

Comment: @MattHickford That's kinda an odd edge case example. That code pipes to $null so `Add-Content` doesn't receive anything. If `Add-Content` doesn't receive anything why should it create a file? On the other hand the same question could be asked of Out-File.

Comment: The difference matters to me `gci $folder | Out-File log.txt ; cat log.txt` works whereas `gci $folder | Add-Content log.txt ; cat log.txt` blows up

Comment: @MattHickford I'd probably make sure the file exists before trying to process it. Probably a good habit for all languages.

Comment: Another difference is that while `Set-Content` is being used, the file is unavailable to other applications.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I would disagree... :)

1. Out-File has -Append (-NoClober is there to avoid overwriting) that will Add-Content. But this is not the same beast.
2. command | Add-Content will use .ToString() method on input. Out-File will use default formatting.

so:

```
ls | Add-Content test.txt
```

and

```
ls | Out-File test.txt
```

will give you totally different results.

And no, '>' is not alias, it's redirection operator (same as in other shells). And has very serious limitation... It will cut lines same way they are displayed. Out-File has -Width parameter that helps you avoid this. Also, with redirection operators you can't decide what encoding to use.

HTH
Bartek

Comment: It is an alias in the meaning that `>` and Out-File are the same thing. They call the same code. From Bruce Payette's PowerShell in Action Second Edition (Kindle Locations 4646): `In fact, myScript > file.txt is just “syntactic sugar” for myScript | out-file -path file.txt In some cases, you’ll want to use Out-File directly because it gives you more control over the way the output is written.`

Comment: Good point about default formatting (Out-File) vs ToString (Add-Content)

Comment: My point was: even though both do generally the same, alias has it's meaning in PowerShell... so I wouldn't use this term to describe relation between those too.. ;) Alias replaces command, in this case it should make syntax: ls | > file.txt possible. Obviously, that won't work...

Comment: Right, that's easily discovered via `Get-Alias`. I used the term in the more general sense.

Comment: FYI `ls | Out-File` is the exact table you see from `ls` whereas `ls | Set-Content` is a simple list of files.

Comment: "Out-File will use default formatting." What exactly is default formatting?

Comment: Default formatting is the way given object is presented in console. Most of core cmdlets/ object types have formatting metadata that informs PowerShell how to display them in user-friendly fashion. In other words: pipeing results of command to Out-File can be used to save output of command to the file, without loosing formatting done by PowerShell.

Comment: Yes, I think it's an important distinction that `>` is not the exact equivalent for `out-file`. If you set `$PSDefaultParameterValues["Out-File:Encoding"] = "UTF8"`, it will be ignored by `>`.

Answer (score 4):

`Set-Content` supports `-Encoding Byte`, while `Out-File` does not.

So when you want to write binary data or result of `Text.Encoding#GetBytes()` to a file, you should use `Set-Content`.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add about difference on encoding:

Windows with PowerShell 5.1:

- Out-File - Default encoding is utf-16le
- Set-Content - Default encoding is us-ascii

Linux with PowerShell 7.1:

- Out-File - Default encoding is us-ascii
- Set-Content - Default encoding is us-ascii

Answer (score 0):

`Out-file -append` or `>>` can actually mix two encodings in the same file.  Even if the file is originally ASCII or ANSI, it will add Unicode by default to the bottom of it.  `Add-content` will check the encoding and match it before appending.  Btw, `export-csv` defaults to ASCII (no accents), and `set-content`/`add-content` to ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR*, use `Set-Content` as it's more consistent over `Out-File`.

1. `Set-Content` behavior is the same over different powershell versions
   `Out-File` as @JagWireZ says produces different encodings for the default settings, even on the same OS(Windows) the docs for [powershell 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1) and [powershell 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.3) state that the encoding changed from `unicode` to `utf8NoBOM`
2. Some issues like [Malformed XML](https://serverfault.com/questions/640165/replacing-a-string-in-an-xml-with-powershell-causes-malformed-xml) arise from using `Out-File`, that could of course be fixed by setting the desired encoding, however it's likely to forget to set the encoding and end up with issues.