# Permission Denied When Trying to Overwrite Hidden File

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have been searching for a while and can't seem to understand why this is happening.

I have a script that maintains a file.  I want to keep that file hidden, but changing the file attribute is causing permissions problems when trying to overwrite it.

Setup is this:

```
"Test Text" | Out-file 'C:\Test\Test.txt' -Force
Set-ItemProperty 'C:\Test\Test.txt' -name Attributes -Value "Hidden"
```

Now if I try to overwrite it like so I get the following error:

```
"New Text" | Out-file 'C:\Test\Test.txt' -Force
```

> Out-file : Access to the path 'C:\Test\Test.txt' is denied. At line:1 char:15
>   + "Test Text" | Out-file 'C:\Test\Test.txt' -Force
>   +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

But permissions don't seem to be the issue because I can get the content and I can remove the file just fine.

```
Get-Content 'C:\Test\Test.txt'

rm 'C:\Test\Test.txt' -force
```

The workaround is to remove the file then write my new one, but I would prefer to maintain the existing file and just add to it if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keith provided a link that explains the permissions issue. Below is my solution to the current problem

Because maintaining the create date of the original file is needed, the workaround I have resorted to is to unhide the file, write to it, then set it back to hidden.

```
Set-ItemProperty 'C:\Test\Test.xml' -name Attributes -Value "Normal"

$myobject | Export-CliXml 'C:\Test\Test.xml' -Force

Set-ItemProperty 'C:\Test\Test.xml' -name Attributes -Value "Hidden"
```

Answer (score 4):

Hidden files have to be deleted before you can "overwrite" them as `Out-File` does (without the `-Append` parameter).  `Add-Content` and `Set-Content` work around this by modifying the existing file's content without overwriting it. See the [docs on the FileMode.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum value.

Comment: Bam. There it is ;) I have a workaround, but its always nice to know the why on these things. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why Out-File is giving this error - it does for me as well. However, Set-Content and Add-Content both work correctly on my system with the -Force parameter:

```
"New Text" | Add-Content C:\test\Test.txt -Force
```

or

```
"New Text" | Set-Content C:\test\Test.txt -Force
```

Edited to add: I was curious as to the difference between Out-File and Set-Content, and found this:

[Powershell set-content and out-file what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655788/powershell-set-content-and-out-file-what-is-the-difference)

It still doesn't quite explain the difference on writing to a hidden file, but may be of interest if you're trying to decide which to use.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful.  I had not considered the set- and add-content cmdlets.  The actual cmdlet I am using is Export-Clixml that has the same permissions issue.  I may see if I can just grab the xml and write it using set-content.

Comment: You could always use ConvertTo-Xml | Set-Content

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried, It sounded good in theory, but the Export-Clixml cmdlet produces special formatting. Using the ConvertTo-XML you lose the formatting needed to import the object later using Import-clixml.