writeLines to hidden files
I have some code that is using writeLines to various files. One of the files is hidden and the code throws an error:
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file 'PATH': Permission denied

The path is declared correctly and if I manually change the file to not be hidden, the code works. So I'm fairly certain that it is an issue with the file being hidden and nothing else.
Has anyone encountered this before and have a work around? When I release the code I will have no control over user environments so the solution can't simply be the manual intervention of setting the file to be unhidden. The solution needs to be programmatic. Thanks all.

What does the code you are running look like exactly? Do you have "PATH" in quotes? Is PATH the hidden file you are talking about?

What makes you think the file is hidden? How did you hide it? And is the file path actually "PATH" or did you change before pasting the text here?

Sorry, I could have been clearer. "PATH" is just me typing over the file path and filename for this post (somewhat sensitive). The point is that it is a simple writeLines command and that the command works with files other than hidden files, so issue is most likely that it is a hidden file under Windows. Not sure how to explain hidden files in windows beyond them being files that are hidden (there is an os level property to view them).

@PDe Ah. The information that this is on Windows was crucial, since on other systems “hidden” files are simply files starting with a dot (.), they are not otherwise special. By contrast, "PATH" is a special value in some contexts, hence the confusion.

This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157761/1968; and also this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode (in other words: this is the expected/desired behaviour for hidden files on Windows).

This is the expected behaviour when attempting to overwrite a hidden file on Windows:

Exceptions
UnauthorizedAccessException
[…]
[Occurs when the open] mode is Create and the specified file is a hidden file.

To overwrite a hidden file, you first need to delete it (via unlink()). Afterwards, you can recreate it as a regular file.
Unfortunately, marking the file as hidden again afterwards from within R doesn’t seem trivial. You could try the following, but I can’t test whether it works:
shell(paste("attrib +h", shQuote(your_filename)))

However, beware that this makes your code non-portable, since shell() only exists on Windows, and will fail on other systems. To keep your code portable, wrap its invocation in a test for the operating system (if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows")).

Great pointer, thank you @Konrad! I actually managed a similar solution but wrapped it in an if to hopefully make it more platform agnostic:
if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
    # Unhide the file (Windows-specific)
    system(paste("attrib -h", file_path))
}

