# Append results or text to text file by using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of objects with properties: ProductName and PartName. The content of collection is output to a file first:

```
$colProducts | sort-object ProductName | `
   Select-object ProductName PartName | `
   Format-Table -autosize ProductName, PartName | `
   Out-File myProducts.txt
```

So far so good. However, I have trouble to append a text message to the result file like this:

```
Add-Content myProducts.txt "`nParts in more than one Product`n"
```

I found that the appended text is not readable at the end. One thing I notice is that the output of the first collection to a file is in Unicode, and the second one code (add-content) is in ASCII if only to a new file.

After this, I would like to continue to add the following information the same result file:

```
$colProducts | Group-object PartName | sort-object PartName | `
   Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1 } | `
   Select-object ProductName PartName | `
   Format-Table -autosize ProductName, PartName | `
   Out-File myProducts.txt
```

The above codes will overwrite to the result file. I need to append to the file. Greatly appreciate help!

**Update:** It is good to know -Append option. How about Add-Content? It seems adding some unreadable chars to the file after Out-File from collection.

Comment: Does Out-File -Append not work?

Comment: You don't need the back-ticks at the end of the lines, by the way. PowerShell lets you end a line with a pipe character.

Answer (score 14):

I would first try:

```
$colProducts | Group-object PartName | sort-object PartName | `
  Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1 } | `
  Select-object ProductName PartName | `
  Format-Table -autosize ProductName, PartName | `
  Out-File -Append myProducts.txt
```

And then look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655788/powershell-set-content-and-out-file-what-is-the-difference) to get a feel for what you were encountering.

Essentially, `Out-File` (and `Out-File -Append`) gives you Unicode by default and `Add-Content` gives ASCII by default. My advice would be stick to the same command and you shouldn't have a problem.

And, of course, `help Out-File -Detailed`! Always check out the powershell examples because they help a great deal, not just to figure out their common usage, but to grok them as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$colProducts | Group-object PartName | sort-object PartName | `
   Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1 } | `
   Select-object ProductName PartName | `
   Format-Table -autosize ProductName, PartName | `
   Out-File -Append myProducts.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
$colProducts | sort-object ProductName | `
   Select-object ProductName PartName | `
   Format-Table -autosize ProductName, PartName | `
   Out-String | Add-Content myProducts.txt 

Add-Content myProducts.txt "`nParts in more than one Product`n"
```