# can't get the foreach output to a file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and i am trying to get the output of foreach loop into a file

the foreach loop looks like:

```
foreach ($element in $ashost)  {get_alerts($element)}
```

i am getting a list of alerts in to the standard output

so i have tried to write the for loop output to a file in the below way:

```
$output =
foreach ($element in $ashost)  {get_alerts($element)}|
$output | Out-File "C:\File.txt"
```

but the file is created empty

note : the "get_alerts" is a function to capture each alert
which i didn't specify a particular return value its just printing to the screen from the 
Write-Host inside the function

Comment: Are you able to modify `get_alerts` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Write-Host append to text file - computer name and time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812239/powershell-write-host-append-to-text-file-computer-name-and-time-stamp)

Comment: If you _didn't specify a particular return value_ in the `get_alerts` function, there won't be anything to save.. Update that function to return the alert(s) to the calling script

Comment: if you are storing the `foreach` output into `$output`, why are you then piping that into `$output` after the `foreach`? You should remove the `|` from the second line or there is something else missing from the code in the post.

Comment: As an aside: In PowerShell, functions are invoked _like shell commands_ - `get_alerts $element $arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `get_alerts($element, $arg2)`; see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects.

Comment: I see that you've at least once before accepted an answer, but - as a refresher - let me recapitulate the advice to newcomers in the next comment. I also encourage you to revisit your previous questions and accept answers there, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

if you return `$element` your `$output` variable should contain the requested data:

```
$output = foreach ($element in $ashost)  {get_alerts($element);$element;}|
$output | Out-File "C:\File.txt"
```

Comment: It'd output `$element` value, not the alerts found

Answer (score 0):

You state that your `get_alerts` function uses `Write-Host` to print to the *screen*.

**`Write-Host`'s output by design isn't sent to PowerShell's *success output stream***<sup>[1]</sup>, so **nothing is captured in `$output`**, so nothing is sent to `Out-File`, which is why you end up with an empty file.

- If you *can* modify the `get_alerts` function, replace `Write-Host` calls with `Write-Output` calls, or just use *implicit* output (e.g., instead of `Write-Host $foo`, use `Write-Output $foo` or simply `$foo`).
- If you *cannot*, and **if you're using PowerShell v5 or higher, you can use redirection `6>&1` to redirect `Write-Host` output to the success output stream**, which allows you to capture it:

```
& { foreach ($elem in $ashost) { get_alerts $elem } } 6>&1 | Out-File C:\File.txt
```

Or, using a single pipeline:

```
$ashost | ForEach-Object { get_alerts $_ } 6>&1 | Out-File C:\File.txt
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50937190/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. In PSv5+ `Write-Host` writes to the [information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection), whose output *can* be captured, but only via `6>`. See also: the last section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375</sup>