# How to redirect a foreach loop output to a file?

Tags: powershell, loops, io-redirection

I'm trying to redirect a foreach loop output to a file with the following powershell code :

```
PS C:\> foreach ( $dir in "c:\ProgramData", "c:\Program Files", "c:\Program Files (x86)" ) { echo "=> $dir :" ; dir -r -fo $dir 2>$null | % FullName | sls 'exe$' } > C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt
```

but the output is displayed on stdout and I get this error :

```
> : The term '>' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:157
+ ... ir :" ; dir -r -fo $dir 2>$null | % FullName | sls 'exe$' } > C:\temp ...
+                                                                 ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (>:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


PS C:\> ls C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt
ls : Cannot find path 'C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ ls C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\>
```

First, I tried replacing the `>` redirection by  `| Out-File C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt` but that did not work :

```
At line:1 char:138
+ ... 6)" ) { dir -r -fo $dir 2>$null | % FullName | sls 'exe$' } | Out-Fil ...
+                                                                 ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement



PS C:\>
```

Then I tried replacing the `>` redirection by  `6>&1 | Out-File C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt` ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408677/cant-get-the-foreach-output-to-a-file-in-powershell/58414212#58414212)) but that did not work either :

```
PS C:\> foreach ( $dir in "c:\ProgramData", "c:\Program Files", "c:\Program Files (x86)" ) { echo "=> $dir :" ; dir -r -fo $dir 2>$null | % FullName | sls 'exe$' } 6>&1 | Out-File C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt
......
6>&1 : The term '6>&1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:157
+ ... :" ; dir -r -fo $dir 2>$null | % FullName | sls 'exe$' } 6>&1 | Out-F ...
+                                                              ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (6>&1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


PS C:\>
```

I expect the output to be inside the file C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt but the file is not even created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already found, flow control statements can't be used in place of commands or value expressions - but you *can* wrap them in a scriptblock and then redirect the output from invoking that instead:

```
& {
  foreach ($dir in "c:\ProgramData", "c:\Program Files", "c:\Program Files (x86)") { 
    echo "=> $dir :" 
    dir -r -fo $dir 2>$null | % FullName | sls 'exe$'
  }
} > C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt
```

---

That being said, you don't actually need a loop here!

You can pipe your input data directly to `Get-ChildItem`, the files discovered by `Get-ChildItem` can in turn be piped to `Where-Object` to filter on their extension, at which point we can grab the `FullName` property value from each resulting subset of files with the `ForEach-Object` command:

```
"c:\ProgramData", "c:\Program Files", "c:\Program Files (x86)" |Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force |Where-Object Extension -eq '.exe' |ForEach-Object FullName |Set-Content C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Thanks a lot. So the short form would be : `"c:\ProgramData", "c:\Program Files", "c:\Program Files (x86)" | dir -r -fo -file 2>$null | % FullName | ? Extension -eq '.exe' > C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt`

Comment: It's not necessarily _the_ short form - there are many other ways you could shorten it - but yes, that'll work. Beware that `>` defaults to UTF16LE encoding on Windows, which is why I prefer piping to `Set-Content`

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen It also seems the order you gave is important because I ended up with an empty file,  so I'll use this from now on : `"c:\ProgramData", "c:\Program Files", "c:\Program Files (x86)" | dir -r -fo -file 2>$null | ? Extension -eq '.exe' | % FullName | sc C:\temp\VDI_Exclustion_List.txt`. I did not know that `>` was creating `UTF16LE` files, I should be more precocious in the future.

Comment: That's probably because of your insistence on `2>$null` after `dir`

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Or maybe after doing a `% FullName` , the `Extension` cannot be inferred because the type of the object has changed.

Comment: @SebMa Correct. `% FullName` dereferences the `FullName` property on the input object and outputs that - so the output from `% FullName` is not a `FileInfo` object, it's just a string. I'd strongly suggest you try it out interactively in a shell. First `"paths" |Get-ChildItem ...`, then `"paths" |Get-ChildItem ... |Where-Object`, then `"paths" |Get-ChildItem ... |Where-Object ... |ForEach-Object`, etc. to get a better grasp on how the pipeline works :)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen One last thing : I noticed here that the `Get-ChildItem` command also works without the `-File` option, do I need the `-File` option of the `Get-ChildItem` command ?

Comment: @SebMa `Select-String` will ignore directory objects, but as a general rule of thumb it's a good idea to specify `-File` when you're specifically looking for files - which is why I added it :) Is there a particular reason/motivation for trying to make it as terse and unreadable as possible?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen OK, I will add it :). No particular reason, I am sometimes kinda lazy so I don't bother typing the whole commands :-D