# Powershell replace adding an empty line

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have this powershell code which should replace every occurrence of a string in every file in the directory with a new string.
This works, however an empty line is added in the end.
What causes this, and how can this be nicely avoided?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $currentDir *.* -recurse
foreach ($file in $files)
    {
    $find = "placeholder"
    $replace = "newvalue"
    $content = Get-Content $($file.FullName) -Raw
    $content -replace $find,$replace | Out-File $($file.FullName) 
    }
```

Simply removing the last line is not a good solution since sometimes my files will contain an empty line which I want to keep.

Comment: All files are in Unicode?

Comment: It's out-file that adds a newline, not -replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `-NoNewline` parameter to prevent `Out-File` from appending the extra line at the end of the file.

```
$content -replace $find,$replace | Out-File $($file.FullName) -NoNewline
```

Note: this was added in PowerShell 5.0

Comment: For prior versions of PowerShell you might consider using `Set-Content` or `Add-Content` but mind the differences with `Out-File`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655788/powershell-set-content-and-out-file-what-is-the-difference

Comment: I put my version in a comment, so that the formatting looks better. I am still limited to PS version 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am limited to PS version 4, and this is what I used

$files = Get-ChildItem $currentDir *.* -recurse

```
$find = "placeholder"
$replace = ""newvalue"    

foreach ($file in $files)
    {
    $content = Get-Content $($file.FullName) -Raw | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $find,$replace}
    $content = $content -join "`r`n"

    $content | Set-Content  $($file.FullName)      
    }
```

Note that this only works if it is ok to store the complete file in memory.