# Why are all newlines gone after PowerShell's Get-Content, Regex, and Set-Content?

Tags: powershell, newline

I want to load a file template into a variable, modify data within the variable and output the modified template to a new location from the variable.

The issue is that PowerShell is removing newlines from my template.

The input file (template file) has Unix line endings which are also required for output since the recipient of the modified version is a Unix-based system.

I have the following code which results into a concatted one-liner:

```
[String] $replacement = "Foo Bar"
[String] $template = Get-Content -Path "$pwd\template.sh" -Encoding UTF8
$template = $template -replace '<REPLACE_ME>', $replacement
$template | Set-Content -Path "$pwd\script.sh" -Encoding UTF8
```

Having the template input:

```
#!/bin/sh
myvar="<REPLACE_ME>"
echo "my variable: $myvar"
exit 0
```

Resulted into:

```
#!/bin/sh myvar="Foo Bar" echo "my variable: $myvar" exit 0
```

It appears to me that somewhere `LF` where replaced by one simple whitespace. Finally at the end of the script there is an added `CR LF` which was not present in the template file.

How do I preserve the line endings and prevent adding further (`CR LF`) *wrong* line endings to the final script?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For the `$replacement` variable, you don't really need to specify the type `[string]`, PowerShell will infer that from the assignment.

For the `$template` variable, `[string]` is actually wrong. By default, `Get-Content` will give you an array of strings (i.e. lines) instead of one string.

But in fact you don't even want to split the input into lines in the first place. When `Set-Content` or `Out-File` see an array as their input, they will join it with spaces.

Using `-Raw` makes `Get-Content` return the entire file as one string, this way also the line endings (like `LF` for Linux files) will stay the way they are.

```
$replacement = "Foo Bar"
$template = Get-Content -Path "$pwd\template.sh" -Encoding UTF8 -Raw
$template = $template -replace '<REPLACE_ME>', $replacement
Set-Content -Path "$pwd\script.sh" -Value $template -Encoding UTF8
```

PowerShell will save all UTF-8 files with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). If you don't want that, you must use a different utility to write the file:

```
$UTF8_NO_BOM = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False

$replacement = "Foo Bar"
$template = Get-Content -Path "$pwd\template.sh" -Encoding UTF8 -Raw
$template = $template -replace '<REPLACE_ME>', $replacement
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$pwd\script.sh", $template, $UTF8_NO_BOM)
```

Notes:

- PowerShell operators (like `-replace`) silently operate on arrays. `$x -replace "search", "replacement"` will perform a replace operation on *every member of $x*, be that a single string or an array of them.
- Recommended reading: *[PowerShell Set-Content and Out-File what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655788/powershell-set-content-and-out-file-what-is-the-difference)*

Comment: The "missing newline situation" is solved with this solution. **However** I now have all `CR LF` instead of just 'LF' which makes UNIX systems fail when the script is being executed. The newlines within the template are definitely just `LF`. Could you expand your answer, please?

Comment: Huh? If you use `-Raw` you should not be in this situation.

Comment: Yeah, I've modified the answer quite a bit because my own assumptions about the origin of the spaces were wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Use the **-delimiter "`n"**  option instead of **-raw**. The ***-raw*** option reads/returns the entire content as a single string, although it preserves the new-line characters but it is useless if you need to manipulate the content e.g. skip Header/1st row or skip blank lines etc.

**Get-Content - background info:**

By default, the `Get-Content` cmdlet reads & returns content line-by-line, which means if you pipe a `Set-Content` or `Add-Content` to instantly write each-line (being read) into the output file - the newline characters are preserved and written as expected, e.g.:

```
Get-Content $inputFile | Set-Content $outputFilePath
```

However, if you store the entire content (read) into a variable (called $variable), your variable will only receive a single string-array WITHOUT the separator/delimiter (by default), which means you will lose the new-line characters, however, when reading file (using `Get-Content`) you can use the `-delimiter` option to specify a newline character (`n), which will then be preserved and written/stored into your $variable, e.g.:

```
Get-Content -Delimiter "`n" $fileToRead
```

HTH.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to use the `-Raw` switch with `Get-Content` in order to load the file as a single string:

```
[String] $replacement = "Foo Bar"
[String] $template = Get-Content -Path "$pwd\template.sh" -Encoding UTF8 -Raw
$template = $template -replace '<REPLACE_ME>', $replacement
```

To stop the Windows line ending being added to the end of the script, I think you need to use this .NET method for writing the file:

```
[io.file]::WriteAllText("$pwd\template.sh",$template)
```

By default PowerShell attempts to convert your input in to an array of strings for each line in the file. I think because of the Unix line endings its not doing this successfully but is subsequently removing the new line characters.

> In PowerShell 3.0 we now have a new dynamic parameter, Raw. When
>   specified, Get-Content ignores newline characters and returns the
>   entire contents of a file in one string. Raw is a dynamic parameter,
>   it is available only in file system drives.

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6026b31a-2a0e-4e0a-90b5-355387dce9ac/preventing-newline-with-outfile-or-addcontent?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: If you do `Get-Help -Name 'Get-Content' -Parameter 'Raw'` you'll see that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `Get-Content-Tail`, which doesn't allow you to specify `-Raw` at the same time, but I did have luck with `Out-String`. So, in your case:

```
$template = Out-String -InputObject $( Get-Content -Path "$pwd\template.sh" -Encoding UTF8 -Raw)
```

Or perhaps, if you care about tail:

```
$template = Out-String -InputObject $(Get-Content -Path "$pwd\template.sh" -tail 4)
```