# Powershell script to write to file maintaining structure

Tags: powershell

I am working with powershell to read in a file. See sample content in the file.

```
This is my file with content
-- #Start
This is more content
across different lines
etc etc
-- #End
```

I am using this code to read in file to a variable.

```
$content = Get-Content "Myfile.txt";
```

I then use this code to strip a particular section from the file and based on opening and closing tag.

```
$stringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder;
$pattern = "-- #Start(.*?)-- #End";
$matched = [regex]::match($content, $pattern).Groups[1].Value; 
$stringBuilder.AppendLine($matched.Trim());
$stringBuilder.ToString() | Out-File "Newfile.txt" -Encoding utf8;
```

The problem that I have is in the file I write to, the formatting is not maintained. So what I want is:

```
This is more content
across different lines
etc etc
```

But what I am getting is:

```
This is more content across different lines etc etc
```

Any ideas how I can alter my code so that in the outputted file the structures is maintained (multiple lines)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are all newlines gone after PowerShell's Get-Content, Regex, and Set-Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512603/why-are-all-newlines-gone-after-powershells-get-content-regex-and-set-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex might do what you're looking for, don't see a point on using a `StringBuilder` in this case. Do note, since this is a multi-line regex pattern you need to use the [`-Raw` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#-raw) to read your file's content.

```bash
$re = [regex] '(?ms)(?<=^-- #Start\s*\r?\n).+?(?=^-- #End)'
$re.Match((Get-Content path\to\Myfile.txt -Raw)).Value |
    Set-Content path\to\newFile.txt -NoNewLine
```

See https://regex101.com/r/82HJxf/1 for details.

---

If you want to do *line-by-line* processing, you could use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) to read and process the lines of interest. This is particularly useful if the file is very big and doesn't fit in memory.

```
& {
    $capture = $false
    switch -Rege -File path\to\Myfile.txt {
        '^-- #Start' { $capture = $true }
        '^-- #End' { $capture = $false }
        Default { if($capture) { $_ } }
    }
} | Set-Content path\to\newFile.txt
```

If there is only one appearance of the opening and closing tag, you could even [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.3) the switch as soon as it encounters the closing tag to stop processing:

```
'^-- #End' { break }
```

Comment: hi @amateur you could use `\s*` for possible whitespace before the tag, i.e.: `(?ms)(?<=^\s*-- #Start\s*\r?\n).+?(?=^\s*-- #End)` see: https://regex101.com/r/Ecq3BC/1. If the answer was helpful please consider accepting it