# how to overwrite file content with power shell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell. how do you over write file in powershell? write now below code is appending. I want to completely over write file with below new info.

$someinfo | Add-Content $FileName

Comment: Have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655788/powershell-set-content-and-out-file-what-is-the-difference#answer-10656021

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `Set-Content` instead of `Add-Content`.

Difference between `Set-Content` and `Add-Content`:
`Add-Content`=> Append
`Set-Content`=> replace content

**Reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 8):

You can do an `Out-File` as well

```
'Some content' | Out-File -FilePath c:\windows\temp\file.log
```