# Powershell preserve byte order mark with Set-Content (search/replace script)

Tags: powershell-4.0

I was using a Powershell script I found to help me rename a BizTalk application.  The maps are stored in .btm files, and must have an XML byte order mark.

After running this script:

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\MyCodePath" *.btm* -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) | 
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "oldstring", "newstring" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

then I got build error: 
 error btm1023: Exception Caught: There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.

Comment: `Set-Content -Encoding Unicode`, or use `Out-File`, which defaults to Unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell set-content and out-file what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10655788/1630171)

Comment: But I wouldn't want to set the -Encoding Unicode for non-Unicode files.  So should I test to see if it's Unicode or not and have two Set-Content statements under an IF Statement?

Comment: Then you need to check the encoding, e.g. like this : `(-join [char[]](Get-Content $file.PSPath -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 2)) -eq 'ÿþ'`.