# powershell: `Out-File` with no wrapping and no padding

Tags: powershell

*UPDATE*: PSVersion 5.1.19041.610

I'm trying to do what I thought was quite simple: save a file list (including some meta-info) in a text file.

```
Get-ChildItem | Out-File test.txt
```

This should do the trick, right?

Unfortunately, every filename that's too long gets wrapped, like following.

```
Directory: C:\temp\test_file_names


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        03.02.2021     13:16              8 some_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_long_f
                                                  ile_name.file
```

Using the `-Width` parameter of `Out-File` removes the wrapping.

```
Get-ChildItem | Out-File -Width 300 test.txt
```

But now every line is padded with spaces to be exactly 300 wide.

Changing `$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize` has the same effect.

Is it possible to somehow get no wrapping and no padding?

Comment: Did you want it formatted as a table? Try `Export-Csv` instead of `Out-File`?

Comment: I want it in a human-readable form, the default output of Get-ChildItem is actually exactly what I want to see.

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem | Format-Table -AutoSize`. I think it will wrap very long names into multiple lines though

Comment: yeah, it does. It's actually kind of the same output as in my example.

Comment: Ah, `format-table` works with the size of your powershell window... Try `gci | Out-String -Width 4096 | out-file` -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973577/commandline-syntax-to-prevent-wrapping-in-powershell-output-file

Comment: every line is 4096 wide, padded with spaces.

Comment: There's a difference in how `-width` works between powershell 5 and 7. No padding in 7. `Get-ChildItem | Out-String -Width 4096 | % { $_ -split '\r?\n' | % { $_.trim() } } | out-file`

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks, the snippet works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue of PS 5 only. Can't reproduce in PS 7.1.

Workaround for PS 5:

```
Get-ChildItem | Out-String -Width 300 -Stream | %{ $_.TrimEnd() } | Out-File test.txt
```

Parameter `-Stream` is used so we process each line separately.

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed. Guess I'll need to upgrade to avoid this kind of headache.

Comment: PowerShell v5x and earlier is completely separate environments from PowerShell Core (v6+). There is no upgrade from Powershell 5x to Powershell Core. It's an install PowerShell Core, thus running PowerShell 5x and PowerShell v6+side-by-side. Unless your whole enterprise/organization is PSCore, then you need to deal with whatever PS version(s) are in your environment.

Comment: Excellent answer. Potentially useful to point out this is good with **any** Powershell command with similar output **and** that increasing `-Width` obviously allows longer lines. For instance, I just used it to help me review a grep of a file with especially long lines: `select-string "MySearchString" .\MyFileName.js | Out-String -Width 8000 -Stream | %{ $_.TrimEnd() } | Out-File test.txt` I wonder if there's a way to say "infinite width"; I tried `0` and got _Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Width'. The 0 argument is less
than the minimum allowed range of 2_ so that's a bust.